# HTML object coordinates

Tags: perl, button, mechanize

This is what I'm trying to emulate using perl mechanize

```html
            <input type="hidden" name="uploadId" value="24753229A1421CB27681A4601B06CF9C">
            <div style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 4px;"><strong>Select and upload your files</strong> (maximum 200 MB each):</div>
            <input type="file" class="file_upload" id="fupload" size="118" name="file_0">
            <div style="margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 15px;"><a href="http://www.zippyshare.com" class="PPToS" style="font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;">New Flash Uploader</a></div>
            <div id="files" style="position: relative; right:0px; top:0px; text-align: right;">
```

which I don't have a problem of emulating to, but the submit button is a little bit tricky,

```html
<input onclick="return start();" type="image" src="/images/upload_small.png" align="middle" style="margin-top: 8px; border: 0;">
```

Its an image, I supposed I can emulate it using mechanize x,y button coordinates but I don't know how to locate coordinates of an object within the html, or are there any possible alternatives?

Comment: [Mechanize doesn't support Javascript, unfortunately.](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#JavaScript) You may be able to discover the URL for a form POST, or you could use an alternative module like WWW::Mechanize::Firefox or Selenium::Remote::Driver which will give you a full-fledged browser instance to control.

Comment: thank you! mechanize::firefox is really cool, this is  exactly what i am looking for, the only thing is that, i dont know how to tell perl to click the button, seems $mech->clickables can't find it, and I dont know what attributes to use.

Comment: Ive done it, with the right xpath everything is fine now :) thanks.